# How to clear input field after submitting form and push values into array (Vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript, html

Onclick of the button I would like to take the values submitted and index them in the empty array. As you can see in the bottom line I have used the reset method on the form but when logging the array, all of the indexes have an empty value.

I have also used preventDefault() to stop the form from submitting, could the form tags be causing the issue?

```js
const enteredNumbers = [];

console.log(enteredNumbers);

const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

form1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const values = document.getElementsByName("number")[0];
  enteredNumbers.push(values);
  form1.reset();
}, true);
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="submit" form="form1" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The form tag does not causing this issue, but 2 other things does:

1. Log the array after each time you submit, and not just on the first time the page renders (the first time the script runs).
2. Your `values` is an *html element*, not the value. The *value* is `elem.value`, that's what I pushed there.

Good luck

```js
const enteredNumbers = [];


const form1 = document.getElementById("form1");

form1.addEventListener("submit", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const values = document.getElementsByName("number")[0];
  enteredNumbers.push(values.value);
  form1.reset();
  console.log(enteredNumbers);
}, true);
```

```html
<form id="form1">
  <div class="row w-100 d-flex justify-content-between div1">
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <input type="number" name="number" id="number" min="1" max="100">
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 d-flex justify-content-center">
      <button type="submit" form="form1" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just relaized I forgot to add the value property to this:

```
document.getElementsByName("number").value
```

Sorry this can be closed